# Cleaned solution and now receive 4 errors on the same line on build attempt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I was working on legacy code and while making changes I cleaned the solution. After that, i tried to compile and  I'm now getting 4 errors:

1. apilabelprinter.h(265) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
2. apilabelprinter.h(265) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
3. apilabelprinter.h(265) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
4. apilabelprinter.h(265) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

I don't know what's causing this. I was building/rebuilding the solution just fine before I cleaned, but now I keep getting the above issues no matter what I do. Does anyone know how to fix this? IDE is visual studio 2008. The line of code giving the error is:

```
virtual void    SetLineThickness( int t ) = 0;
```

Class where the problem is occuring:

```
class APIDLL_API ILabelGraphic : virtual public ILabelItem
    {
    public:

        /// Set the width (in pixels).
        virtual void    SetWidth( int w ) = 0;

        /// Set the height (in pixels).
        virtual void    SetHeight( int h ) = 0;

        /// Set the line thickness (in pixels).
        virtual void    SetLineThickness( int t ) = 0;

        enum eLineColor
        {
            eLineColor_Black,       ///< Plain ol' black line.
            eLineColor_White        ///< Stunning white line.
        };

        /// Set the line color.
        virtual void    SetLineColor( eLineColor lc ) = 0;
    };
```

ILabelItem Class:

```
class APIDLL_API ILabelItem
    {
    public:
        /// Set the Label Text position (in pixels).
        virtual void    SetPosition( int x, int y ) = 0;

        /// Return the current object equivalent in ZPL code.
        virtual string  ToZPLCode() = 0;
    };
```

Comment: `virtual string  ToZPLCode() = 0;`?? Perhaps `virtual std::string  ToZPLCode() = 0;` will work.

Comment: So which is line 265? It helps to indicate where the errors are when posting code.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't thinking when I posted this. the line giving me the error is: virtual void    SetLineThickness( int t ) = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment, the line that was giving me trouble was:

```
virtual void SetLineThickness( int t ) = 0;
```

I apologize for not giving that detail. After combing over the code, i figured out what it was. I was setting up a new combo box in the UI, at one point it accidentally was named "t". I caught this and renamed in before I moved on to other code changes. As a result, in a Resource.h t was already defined:

```
#define t  1014
```

Since there was no references to the 't' combo box (I caught the name typo and renamed the combo box before I left the .rc file), i was able to just delete the above line of code and the errors disappeared.